# Excel - Making any border that's "xlThick" into "xlMedium"

Tags: vba, excel

Self Answered...I figured it out.

```
For CellA = 1 To 20
For CellB = 1 To 40
    Set Curcell = ActiveSheet.Cells(CellB, CellA)
    Curcell.Select
    For i = 1 To 4
        If i = 1 Then X = "xlEdgeBottom"
        If i = 2 Then X = "xlEdgeLeft"
        If i = 3 Then X = "xlEdgeRight"
        If i = 4 Then X = "xlEdgeTop"

         **If Selection.borders(X) = xlThick Then** Selection.borders(X) = xlMedium

    Next i

   Next CellB
Next CellA
```

My Goal: if a border is thick, make it medium. All the cells will fall within the range, but they're in multiple sheets.

Why doesn't this work? I have a "type mismatch" at " If Selection.borders(X) = xlThick Then"

I know it's crude but shouldn't it work? What can I do? I have googled but maybe I'm typing in the wrong words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Sub borders()

For CEllA = 1 To 20
    For CellB = 1 To 40
        Set Curcell = ActiveSheet.Cells(CellB, CEllA)
        Curcell.Select

            If Selection.borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick Then Selection.borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
            If Selection.borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick Then Selection.borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
            If Selection.borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick Then Selection.borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
            If Selection.borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick Then Selection.borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium

    Next CellB

Next CEllA



End Sub
```

Comment: I know you self answered this, but there may be a better way.  Do all of the cells in the range have a thick border and you're looking to turn them medium?  or is there a mix of thicknesses and you only want the heavy to be toned down?

Comment: There are some that have xlthin as well but I want them to stay thin. I figured there would be a better way, but this is what I figured out fast and it did what I needed it to at the time. It's an ugly way :-P

Comment: sure, the main thing is you solved your current issue.  For future reference, if you didn't already know, you can leave off the (xlEdgeBottom), (xlEdgeLeft), (xlEdgeRight), and (xlEdgeTop) if you want to apply formatting to all the boarders at once.  So you can do what you want in one line of code if they were all the same thickness and you wanted all four edges to look the same.

Comment: I figured at much but there were instances that a thick border was only needed in one part of a cell, so I didn't want to apply it to all of the cell. Also, if I did that this way, wouldn't it cascade so that every cell has that border?

Comment: It's hard to gauge your sheet layout and balance that with your skill set.  For a long time I was applying consistent borders like you outlined in your code, until someone showed me you can do it in one line of code, so I was just putting it out there as a reference. Also, you can speed up your process by quite a bit by not selecting the cells and just applying the formatting directly to the cell.

Comment: would I do a "for each cell in range/document" kind of method to speed it up? I have completed the task with this code, and it'd be nice to know how to be more effecient.

Comment: Yep.  There is only a very, very, very few instances where you have to actually select the cell.  Your better bet would be to define a range and then do a for each within that range.  It'll be even faster if you start the routine by setting Application.ScreenUpdating to false.  Even though you've finished the project, it may be worth refactoring that bit of code just to see how much of a difference it makes.